# Creating a web app that authenticates users from two different databases

Tags: cross-platform, multi-platform

I am in a bit of an awkward programming situation, and it will help me a lot to get your input in this situation.

I am building a web app which expects to authenticate users from another, separate application (through API calls), and also authenticate users from it's own database. Essentially, there are two separate user bases.

Let's say the app I'm building is App1, and the other app which I'm making API calls to is App2. This communication is only one-way; App1 makes API calls to App2, but App2 does not make calls to App1. Users can register in App1 and create an account in App1's database - but during this process, App1 makes an API call to App2 to make sure the email/username being entered into App1 is not already present in App2.

Now, the other side of this. If a user is already registered in App2, they do not need to go and register again in App1. They can simply go to App1 and log in. In doing so, App1 sends an API call to App2 to authenticate the user, and creates a copy of the App2 user's account in it's own (App1) database.

Problems arise when there are two distinct users, one in App1, and the other in App2, that share the same username. Now, when the App2 user attempts to log into App1, there will exist two users in App1 with the same username! How can a scenario like this be avoided? Is this even a place I want to be (working with App2's user base)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **two ways** in which two distinct users sharing the same name (XYZ) may come to exist in both apps.

**First** situation:

- User XYZ already exists in App2.
- Another user also named XYZ, but not the same person, tries to register in App1 but gets authenticated in App2 first, because somehow the password happens to be the same of App2's XYZ user, and a copy of the account is created in App1.

**Second** situation:

- User XYZ already exists in App1.
- Another user also named XYZ, but not the same person, registers in App2 and, since there's no communication from App2 to App1, the creation of such a user succeeds.

The first situation is very hard to come by. If App2 demands the password to be non-trivial, the possibilities of two users creating the exact same password is small.

The second situation is very probable. In that case when App1's XYZ user tries to login, the authentication against App2's database will fail because passwords don't match and the user will not be able to register in App1.

**Possible solution**

- First find out what's the unique identifier of users in App2. Is it the username? Is it an email address ?
- If it's an email address, being an email address an externally generated ID that can't repeat, you should also make the email address and not the username the identifier in App1.
- If it's username that provides unicity in App2, then we are out of luck. Since you have no control of App2, you can't possibly prevent a distinct person from creating an account with the exact username that exists on an unrelated application.
- Find out if App2 uses a 3rd party authentication authority ( see bellow ) and adopt it yourself.
- The only way to make such interoperability is making both App1 and App2 resort to a 3rd party to generate identity. An example of that is using an mail address as identifier ( users need access to the email address to successfully register since a link to complete the registration is sent to that address ), or using Facebook or Goole like StackExchange does, or another provider of centralized authentication.

**If nothing of the above applies**, and since App1 is using App2 as authentication authority without App2 knowing, and since you don't have control over App2, then you such re-consider the whole relationship with App2.